# A software on each computer in a classroom in which students can send their answers to the teacher's

Tags: windows, file-management

I teach programming in a class - a real one not a virtual and online one. I ask my students to write a code during the class, and then I go on their desks and see their code, and I evaluate it and assign a mark(grade) for each individual or group. Then I rank them based upon the mark and also the duration of time they needed to do the coding. So I wanted to know if there is a software or platform via which students send their code to my computer directly as soon as they finish it so I can see the time they sent it to me. Moreover, if such a thing exists, the other students or groups can see their classmates codes while I'm correcting it as they are seeing my computer screen projected on the classroom wall.

Comment: This can be achieved in many different ways. Are you looking for more of online or offline (or local network) solution?

Comment: If local network solution is easy to implement please tell me that. If not tell me the online method. We could connect all laptops to the internet and use the online method(s), too.